# jQuery UI autocomplete vertical scrollbar in IE

Tags: jquery-ui

When moving through the list of suggestions in IE the graphic indicating the currently selected item extends past the vertical scrollbar.  Is there a way to keep it within the visible area of the list?

I'm using IE7 and jQuery UI 1.8.16.

I have the autocomplete styled like so:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
 width: 190px;
 max-height: 132px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

* html .ui-autocomplete {
  height: 132px;
}

.ui-autocomplete li {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

already tried overflow-y: scroll; ?

You can't use "auto" without setting a fixed height, and I think "max-height" didn't work on IE7.

Good luck!